# Bind scope function to output event in angular hybrid application

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, hybrid, angular-output

I am using angular hybrid application. I have a directive created in angular js. It has a scope method called `onUpdateStatusCompleted`. The directive has an angular js component inside it.

The link method is used in the component as `after-completed="onUpdateStatusCompleted"`. `AfterCompleted` is a function in the component. I have converted this component to angular 16 now. I have created event Emitter for `after-completed` in my new updated component. When I do `(after-completed)="onUpdateStatusCompleted"` or `(after-completed)="onUpdateStatusCompleted()"` the scope method is not being hit.

How to bind angular js directive's scope method to angular output?

Comment: It worked when I declared `afterCompleted` as input instead of output and define as function.